# Date validation is not working

Tags: java, parsing, validation, date

Date validation is not working properly.
If day = 90, month = 1 and year = 1990
The validation does not work. It switches the date to march, with no validation.
How can I validate it?

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date date;

try {
    date = formatter.parse(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    error = Boolean.TRUE;
    errorMessage = "Invalid date";
    return null;
}
```

Comment: it is duplication, my bad, i'll delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `setLenient()` method, which stupidly defaults to `true`.

Nonetheless, I think there are still some issues even with it set to `false`. You might want to consider looking at JodaTime which makes this much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing something . Simpledataformat will just check for data format. It will roll over date if the date is invalid (feb 30th becomes march 1st). So once you check the format also check if the date is same.

(!sdf.format(date).equals(dateString))
        {
          errorMessage = "The date that you provided is invalid.";
          return false;
        }